# Drupal - How do I block (eliminate access) content in front page from anonymous user

Tags: drupal

How do I block (eliminate access) content in front page from anonymous user. Where can I find the option to change the settings.

Comment: what content do u want to block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7, go to people and then the permissions tab, here you can deselect 'View published content' for anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to set access to content in drupal.

You can show blocks based on what role a user has and also set permissions by content type.

Options vary and how it accomplished depending on what drupal version you use.